# Getting started with E2E Testing

Tags: e2e-testing

I am very new to testing. I needed to get started with E2E testing scripts from scratch. Could anyone please guide me where to start from? Any books or youtube channel?

I have installed Selenium, VS Code and Visual Studio but none of the tutorials I saw use Visual Studio. I may be wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what programming language are you planning to use ? and also what is the technology stack of the software undertest ?

Comment: I am using C# and Selenium for backend development

Comment: I think this might be helpful 

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/

you need to start from the basics.. but always learn by doing don't spend so much time reading and watching tutorial .. start coding and trying out right away!

Good luck